# Error parsing json with Swift4, imposible to print it

Tags: json, swift, decodable

I've been working on Swift and it's impossible to parse my JSON. I've created the struct with http://www.jsoncafe.com/ , everything looks great, optional values, coding keys, etc. But all the time I get this Error.

> Error dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.})))

This is my code.

```
func fetchData() {
    guard let gitUrl = URL(string: "https://www.zaragoza.es/sede/servicio/farmacia.json?tipo=guardia") else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: gitUrl) { (data, response
        , error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let guardia = try decoder.decode([Result].self, from: data)
            print(guardia.first?.title as Any)

        } catch let err {
            print("Error", err)
        }
        }.resume()

}
```

JSON:

```
    { "totalCount": 12, 
"start": 0,
  "rows": 50,
  "icon": "farmaciaguardia",
  "result": [
    {
      "id": 8747,
      "title": "Farmacia De Miguel Golvano, Cristóbal",
      "telefonos": "976220481",
      "horario": "Lunes a Sábado excepto festivos de 9:30 a 22:00 h",
      "clasificacion": "HorarioAmpliado",
      "calle": "Pº de Sagasta, 13",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -0.8857963286144336,
          41.643332650243835
        ]
      },
      "guardia": {
        "fecha": "2019-04-20T00:00:00Z",
        "turno": "T-05",
        "horario": "Abiertas de 9:15 h. a 9:15 h. del día siguiente",
        "sector": "Sector Centro-Esquina C/ Bolonia"
      },
      "type": [
        "http://www.zaragoza.es/sede/portal/skos/vocab/FarmaciaGuardia/2019-04-20",
        "http://www.zaragoza.es/sede/portal/skos/vocab/FarmaciaHorarioAmpliado"
      ]
    }]}
```

Comment: Can you share the JSON struct pls?

Comment: The error seems quite clear.

Comment: Anand, you've there the JSON, this is the structure, alse the URL is in the code because the JSON response is quite long. Sure the error is clear... but not for me...I've checked all the info but all the time I get nothing, even using quitcktype or jsoncafe, this is the reason that I now that structs are great created and the problema is the calling to JSON, and how I implement the code to get the values, but I don't know other way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally get it.
There is a problem with headers. This is the answer. Thanks a lot.

```
func fetchData() {

            let url = URL(string: "https://www.zaragoza.es/sede/servicio/farmacia.json?tipo=guardia")
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")  // the request is JSON
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                do {
                    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let responseModel = try jsonDecoder.decode(Result.self, from: data!)
                    print(responseModel)
                } catch {
                    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }

            }
            task.resume()

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re telling the decoder that your JSON response has a top level element of an array but it doesn’t. The array is in a nested property called result. You need to create something like

```
struct ResultToDecode: Decodable {
   let result: [Result]
}
```

Comment: Hi I've it. Al the decodable structs, like I said I created them in http://www.jsoncafe.com/ , I've triend to calling all the ways I 've seen in all the examples that I've found, but nothing works.